# Add http-equiv redirect via code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh

I'm trying to add an http-equiv refresh via code behind to an aspx page.

I've tried

```
HtmlMeta refreshMetaKey = new HtmlMeta();
refreshMetaKey.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
refreshMetaKey.Content = String.Format("{0};url={1}", redirectTimeInSeconds.ToString(), redirectUrl);
HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
head.Controls.Add(refreshMetaKey);
```

as well as

```
HtmlMeta refreshMetaKey = new HtmlMeta();
refreshMetaKey.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
refreshMetaKey.Content = String.Format("{0};url={1}", redirectTimeInSeconds.ToString(), redirectUrl);
Page.Header.Controls.Add(refreshMetaKey);
```

But I'm getting object not set to an instance on ...Controls.Add() on both methods.  Any ideas?  Or even better ways to do this (FYI, I can't set in markup or use Javascript).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this being run in `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Page is null.  Therefore Page.Header is giving you the `Object not set to an instance` error.

```
HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
```

Other than that, your code is right on.

Comment: this code was in OnPreInit().  by moving to OnLoad(), the Page was not null.  Thanks!